# Verifying Picards Big Theorem for the functions $\sin(z^{-1})$ and $e^{P(z)}$ for $P$ a non-constant polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show directly (by computation) the following two things:

1. For the function $f\left(z\right)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$
   given any neighborhood $U$
   of $z=0$
   and any $\omega\in\mathbb{C}$
   there are infinitely many values $z\in U$
   such that $f\left(z\right)=\omega$
2. The same for the function $f\left(z\right)=e^{P\left(z\right)}$ given $P$ a non-constant polynomial and the essential singularity of $f$ at infinity.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second function, you are trying to solve $\log w = P(z)+2\pi i k.$ This is a polynomial equation in $z,$ so has a root. For large $k,$ that root will be very large also. For the second, express $\arcsin$ in terms of logs, and do the same...

Comment: Could you elaborate about the first one? not sure what you meant by expressing arcsin in term of logs.

Comment: @Serpahimz well, $u=\sin x = \frac12(\exp i x - 1/\exp i x.$ So, notice that if you know u, you get a quadratic equation in $\exp i x.$ You can solve it, and then take logs to get the actual $i x$ (or, in your case, the actual $i/x.$ Since you can add multiples of $2\pi i$ to the logs with impunity, you are good to go.

Comment: Regarding the second function, suppose $z_{0}$ is the solution of $P\left(z\right)=\ln\omega$, how does adding a large multiple of $2\pi i$ help me? I can get $e^{P\left(z_{0}\right)+2\pi ki}=e^{P\left(z_{0}\right)}=\omega$ but that's not what I need.

Comment: @Serpahimz You want to get a $z$ of large absolute such that $\exp(P(z)) = w.$ What I am suggesting is finding some solution, then adding enough multiples of $2\pi i$ to make it big.

Comment: Ye but if $z_{0}$ is a solution such that $e^{P\left(z_{0}\right)}=\omega$ what does looking at $z_{0}+2\pi i\cdot k$ give me, it doesn't give me $e^{P\left(z_{0}+2\pi ki\right)}=\omega$ so I don't get a solution of large absolute value.

Comment: @Serpahimz good point, I was typing too quickly. Instead look for a root of $P(z) = \log w + 2\pi i k.$ As $k$ becomes very large, all solutions of this become large also.

Comment: Great, that does it indeed, thank you very much Igor.